# Как переименовать 10 миллионов файлов в одной папке

Tags: windows

Имеется группа файлов в одном каталоге с именами

```
12345.jpeg 
asdfafsa.jpeg 
...
```

Нужно привести их к значению

```
1.jpeg 
2.jpeg 
и так далее.
```

Total Commander умирает при таком количестве файлов (порядка 10 миллионов).
ОС Win7 x64

Comment: Как именно переименовать? Какой алгоритм замены? Как "умирает" тотал?

Comment: Согласно вики, тотал жив: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander Бета-версия 9.0 beta 10 (17 августа 2016)

Comment: @Other вероятно имелось в виду "не справляется"

Comment: Скриптец на Питоне и на ночь поставить

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, тогда уж на плюсах, будет быстрее и не очень-то сложнее.

Comment: Вообще нужно по цифрам хотя бы. То есть в итоге получить файлы с именами 1.jpg 2.jpg ... как то так.

Comment: Как Вы попытались решить проблему?

Comment: Использованием всевозможного софта что не привело к результатам. В идеале хотел бы получить наводку на подходящий софт или способ решения в среде win7

Comment: ОК, начнём: Тотал умер, скриптик в PowerShell?

Comment: Сложно мне придется. Скрипты писать не самый любимый мой конек.  Но попробую разобраться.

Comment: Как же вы дожились до 10 миллионов файлов в одной папке?

Comment: Производственная задача. Долго объяснять, но так хранятся файлы понимаю что глупость но это временное хранение.

Answer (score 8):

Через bat-файл

```
@echo off

   set all=0   
   set dir=D:\work\1\
   set dim=xls
   set new=file_change
   set mask=filex


for %%x in ("%dir%*.*") do (set /A all+=1)


for /l %%y in (1,1,%all%) do (if exist "%dir%%mask%*%%y*.%dim%" (rename "%dir%%mask%*%%y*.%dim%" "%new%%%y.%dim%") else (echo files are not found))
pause
```

Попробуй тогда так (файл помести в папку с файлами):

```
@echo off
set j=0
for %%i in (*.jpeg) do (
set /a j+=1
call :renamefile %%i %j
)
goto :end
:renamefile
ren %1 %j%.jpeg
:end
```

*P.S. только проблема с русскоязычными именами*

Comment: files are not found
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . . Уточню расширение файлов jpeg Месторасположение указал свое.

Comment: @Алексей а вы папку в батнике заменили? с D:\work\1\ на вашу

Comment: Да разумеется.  + Вроде скобку закрыл. Все как Вы и написали. Подумал что возможно проблема в 4 символьном расширении файла

Comment: Та же ситуация, только теперь несколько раз пишет что файл не найден и закрывается. Пробовал кодировку менять безрезультатно.

Comment: Попробуй второй вариант, который я выложил. Он работает, проверял на Windows 7 (x64), может быть в пути указан "Русский" язык, с ним он работает плохо

Comment: Да большущее спасибо все работает. Не хотело работать из за кириличных путей и имен файлов.

Comment: + Не сразу разобрался с учетом спец символов там если в именах файлов есть скобки он не срабатывает. Но теперь зато работает, в принципе часть имен со скобками очень маленькая я ее тоталом переименую. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Было бы за что - обращайся еще)